# Change Step Area Color Based on Value

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, canvasjs

I'm using CanvasJS and ChartJS and was wondering if it was possible to have a different color of area based on value of point? I'm populating the chart from a rest api

Here is my javascript:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: '/getdata',
        success: function (response) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(response);
            var containter = document.getElementById("chart");

            var data = [];

            json.forEach(function(item){
                var date = new Date(item.time);
                    date = ("00" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
                        ("00" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" +
                        ("00" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + "." +
                        ("00" + date.getMilliseconds()).slice(-3);

                var obj = {
                    y : item.price,
                    label : date
                };

                data.push(obj);
            });

            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(containter,{
                axisY: {
                    title: "Price"
                },
                axisX: {
                    labelAngle: -45
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        type: "stepArea",
                        dataPoints: data
                    }
                ]
            });

            chart.render();

        }
    });
```

So in this example I'd like if price is in range 4.00 to 7.99 to have a green area color, if price is 8.00 to 11.99 to have a yellow color and if higher than 12 to have a red color.

Is this possible?

Comment: Your code is for canvasjs not chartjs. Are you looking for a chartjs solution or was that a typo? (you don't ordinarily see 2 chart libraries being used in the same project)

Comment: This comment is with canvasjs code, but I've got also code for chartjs for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Chart.js bar chart (~ step area chart) to do this, like so

```
Chart.types.Bar.extend({
    name: "BarAlt",
    initialize: function (data) {
        Chart.types.Bar.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        this.datasets
            .filter(function (dataset) {
                // only do this for the arrays
                return typeof (dataset.fillColor) === "object";
            })
            .forEach(function (dataset) {
                dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
                    dataset.fillColor.forEach(function (range) {
                        if (bar.value >= (range.from || -Infinity) && bar.value < (range.to || Infinity))
                            // set the bar color, the tooltip hover color and the cached (used to restore after a tooltip hover) color based on the value
                            bar.fillColor = bar.highlightFill = bar._saved.fillColor = range.fillColor;
                    })
                })
            })
    }
});
```

where the chart data has an array (instead of a string) for `fillColor`, like so

```
datasets: [
    {
        ...
        // sorted range with colors
        fillColor: [
            { to: 50, fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)" },
            { from: 50, to: 75, fillColor: "rgba(220,0,0,0.2)" },
            { from: 75, to: 100, fillColor: "rgba(0,0,220,0.5)" },
            { from: 100, fillColor: "rgba(0,0,220,0.2)" },
        ],
        ...
```

Remember to call the chart using `BarAlt` instead of `Bar`

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hhybyhfw/

---

[image]